# не получается правильно десериализовать теги XML в объекты хранящиеся в коллекции

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

В лекции сказано, что будут созданы объекты: zoo, несколько cat и dog. Однако, попытка проверить это выдает, что у ArrayList в качестве элементов  совсем другое: *class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl*

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

public class MMM {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException
    {
        String xmldata = "<zoo><cat/><cat/><dog/><cat/><cat/></zoo>";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmldata);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Cat.class, Zoo.class, Dog.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        Zoo zoo = (Zoo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        System.out.println("Inf about result object:\n");
        System.out.println("class: " + zoo.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("field's class: " + zoo.animals.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println(zoo.animals.size());

        System.out.println("classes of elements");
        for (Object object : zoo.animals)
            System.out.println(object.getClass());

    }

    @XmlType(name = "cat")
    @XmlRootElement
    static class Cat
    {
        public String name;
        public int age;
        public int weight;

        Cat() { }
    }

    @XmlType(name = "zoo")
    @XmlRootElement
    static class Zoo
    {
        @XmlAnyElement
        public List<Object> animals;
    }

    @XmlType(name = "dog")
    @XmlRootElement
    static class Dog
    {
        public String name;
        public int age;
        public int weight;

        Dog() { }
    }
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно, так чтобы все же получить в ArrayList объекты...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте,

Похоже Вы ищите что-то вроде:

```
@XmlElements({
      @XmlElement(name = "dog", type = Dog.class),
      @XmlElement(name = "cat", type = Cat.class)
})
public List<Object> getAnimals() {
      return animals;
}
```

В данном случае приложение сможет определить какой именно класс должен быть использован для каждого конкретного тэга.

Кроме того, многие рекомендуют создавать для таких целей интерфейсы, в результате чего может получиться что-то вроде:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws JAXBException {
        String xmldata = "<zoo><cat><name>Tomcat</name></cat><dog>erer</dog></zoo>";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmldata);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Zoo.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        Zoo zoo = (Zoo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        for (Animal object : zoo.getAnimals()) {
            System.out.println(object.getClass() + " " + object.getName());
        }
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "zoo")
class Zoo {
    private List<Animal> animals;

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "dog", type = Dog.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "cat", type = Cat.class)
    })
    public List<Animal> getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }

    public void setAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
    }
}

interface Animal {
    String getName();
}

class Cat implements Animal {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Dog implements Animal {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Результат вывода:

```
class Cat Tomcat
class Dog null
```

Но это уже дело вкуса и многим такая тавтология не нравится.

Надеюсь ответил на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое!